# The $\big\{\{a,b\}\mid a\in A\wedge b\in B\big\}$ operator

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Given two sets $A$ and $B$ we can define:
$$
C=\big\{\{a,b\}\mid a\in A\wedge b\in B\big\}
$$
I was wondering if there a common name/definition for this kind of operator?

Comment: Is the pair $\{a,b\}$ supposed to be ordered? If so, it's just cartesian multiplication. If not, $C$ could be fairly easily be derived from the cartesian product.

Comment: @Angelica It's not ordered

Comment: How do you derive from the cartesian product?

Comment: Use the following def of *ordered pair*: $(a,b) = \{ \{ a \}, \{ a,b \} \}$. Then $x \in \bigcup  \{ \{ a \}, \{ a,b \} \} \leftrightarrow \exists z \in \{ \{ a \}, \{ a,b \} \} (x \in z)$

Comment: If so, $\{ a,b \} = \{ x \mid x \in \bigcup (a,b) \}$